# JSDAI error: Dictionary data file is missing for schema

Tags: java, eclipse, schema, step

I'm using Eclipse with JSDAI to extract data out of a STEP file. I have followed the tutorial but end up with the error,

Dictionary data file is missing for schema "config_control_design" (jsdai/SConfig_control_design/CONFIG_CONTROL_DESIGN_DICTIONARY_DATA)

Here is my code

```
public class StepExtraction {
public static void main(String args[]) throws SdaiException {
    java.util.Properties prop = new java.util.Properties();
    prop.setProperty("repositories", "/Users/name/Repos");
    SdaiSession.setSessionProperties(prop);
    SdaiSession session = SdaiSession.openSession();
    SdaiTransaction transaction = session.startTransactionReadWriteAccess();
    SdaiRepository repository = session.importClearTextEncoding("MyRepo", "/Users/name/Downloads/cylinder.stp", null);
    if(!repository.isActive()) {
        repository.openRepository();
    }
    transaction.commit();

    ASdaiModel models = repository.getModels();
    SdaiIterator modelIterator = models.createIterator();
    while(modelIterator.next()) {
        SdaiModel model = models.getCurrentMember(modelIterator);
    }
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ok I fixed it. I just made my own EXPRESS jar with the schema source code from steptools.com for config_control_design and then added it to my library dependancies and it worked! Hopefully this might be useful to somebody in the future.

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I fixed it myself. I just made my own EXPRESS jar with the schema source code from steptools.com for config_control_design and then added it to my library dependancies and it worked!

Hopefully this might be useful to somebody in the future.